# How to read the form's inputs by type?

Tags: php, arrays, forms, post

I have a form:

```
<form name="form1" method="post" action="form_to_write.php">
    <h4>q1</h4>
    <input type="radio" name="a1" value="someValue1" />someValue1<br />
    <input type="radio" name="a1" value="someValue2" />someValue2<br />
    <input type="radio" name="a1" value="someValue3" />someValue3
    <h4>q2</h4>
    <input type="radio" name="a2" value="someValue4" />someValue4<br />
    <input type="radio" name="a2" value="someValue5" />someValue5<br />
    <input type="radio" name="a2" value="someValue6" />someValue6
    <h4>q3</h4>
    <input type="radio" name="a3" value="someValue9" />someValue9<br />
    <input type="radio" name="a3" value="someValue7" />someValue7<br />
    <input type="radio" name="a3" value="someValue8" />someValue8
    <input type="submit" value="submit" name="submit"/>
</form>
```

And want to read all inputs to array by type (radio). I know, how to read it by name, but how by type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

make your `form_to_write.php` like this:

```
<?php
print_r($_POST);
```

and study it's output.
It contains everything you can get from the form. You are free to choose what to use. Enjoy.

As your question being a perfect example of a badly asked question, I can only *guess* your *real needs*.

It seems you want to get an array contains all radio buttons. You still can do it by using names.

make your radio buttons names like this

```
<input type="radio" name="radios[a1]" value="someValue1" />someValue1<br />

<input type="radio" name="radios[a2]" value="someValue4" />someValue4<br />

<input type="radio" name="radios[a3]" value="someValue9" />someValue9<br />
```

and you'll be able to access `$_POST['radios']` array which contains all your radio fields

Answer (score 3):

The input `type` attribute is not sent to the server when the form is submitted. Only the `name` and the `value` are sent. You will need to keep track of what's what yourself on the server using useful `name`s.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for a PHP function like `GetAllInputsOfType("radio")` then you won't find it (unless you can do somethign fancy with the DOM, like JS does; [maybe this will help](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/)?).

What I have done in similar circumstances is to rename my input fields according to type, so instead of a1, a2, a3, you could have radio_a1, radio_a1, radio_a3 and text_a4, memo_a5, listbox_a6, etc (and, btw, use some *meaningful* names, not a1, a2, a3 ;-)

Then you can loop thorough the array $_GET or $_POST looking for elements beginning `radio_` ...

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like a Zend_Form which keeps track of it (and could even do validating jobs etc). But you can't get the type of a form field with just php - you'll need to do things in JS which is on the client side and may not be trusted.